# Runtime.getRuntime exec

Tags: java, android

I have created a class to handle root commands in an android app, which is working just fine mostly. I create the process with Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") and then enter commands using DataOutputStream and get the data from the commands using DataInputStream and the deprecated readLine. (I have tried using BufferedReader instead, but no difference to the issue).

My problem is that the app will hang if the command produces an error. F.eks. if I execute the command "[ -f /test ] && md5sum /test" || echo 0" I will have no problems. However, if I execute "md5sum /test" and the file does not exist, I will have to force-close the app as it will get nowhere. In this example the solution is of cause just to check for the file like in the first example, but not every situation is this simple. Issues can happen, and when they do, people should not have to force-close applications.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: You probably aren't reading its stdout/stderr streams completely and correctly

Comment: Okay, could you provide an example of how to do to this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Your app is likely hanging because you probably aren't processing stderr/stdout generated by the spawned process.  The reason behind this is that spawned processes have very small output buffers (usually only a few kilobytes).  Once those buffers are full, that process will hang until its buffers free up enough space for it to continue writing output text.  I suspect you're having problems when running that second command because that second command is failing and generating lots of console output.  Your child process runs out of buffer space and then tries to block until more space becomes available, which never happens.

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` returns an instance of `Process`.  `Process` objects have an accessor method (I believe it's `getInputStream()`) that allow you to consume its stdout.  You also need to do the same with `getErrorStream()`.  Typically, I get the `InputStream`, then have a separate thread continually consume data from that `InputStream` until it's closed.  You don't need to do anything with the data per se, just read it.  This will tell the underlying process that it can clear its output buffers, hopefully before they ever become full (thus, causing the Process to block).

Also, I'm not 100% familiar with Android, but in plain ol' java, it's better to use `ProcessBuilder` to spawn child `Process` instances.  This is because `ProcessBuilder` lets you combine the child's stderr AND stdout in the same stream, which lets you consume both within a single thread by just reading data from the stream returned by `process.getInputStream()`.

Comment: Wow thanks. That makes perfect sense. I will play around with this, and also have a look at ProcessBuilder. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have looked at ProcessBuilder (Which exists for android as well). But I still run into to a problems.

```
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    data = line;
}

if (data != null && data.contains("uid=0")) {
    return true;
}
```

This will provide the same issue as before. It get's nowhere. However, if I change the code to

```
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    if (data != null && data.contains("uid=0")) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This will work fine. The process will come to an end, and it will return true. The problem is that in order for me to use this, I would have to know exacly what to expect as the return data (Which I do in this test method). So this cannot be the solution.

Here are the entire testing method

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("su");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    Process process = builder.start();
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);

    output.writeBytes("id\n");
    output.flush();

    String line = null;
    String data = null;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        data = line;
    }

    if (data != null && data.contains("uid=0")) {
        return true;
    }

} catch(Throwable e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Root access rejected [" + e.getClass().getName() + "] : " + e.getMessage());
}

return false;
```

Comment: Okay I made a solution that seams to be working fine. After output.writeBytes(cmd + "\n") you add output.writeBytes("echo EOL:a00c38d8:EOL\n"), right before output.flush(). Then in the loop you can do while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null && !"EOL:a00c38d8:EOL".equals(line)) and grap the last line, before readLine hangs, waiting for the next line to come in.